# ConcurrentDictionary as cache

Tags: c#

I have `ConcurrentDictionary<string, SomeClass>` which I use as not expiring cache. I want to periodically update it from external data source. 
I can use `TryUpdate` or similar methods to populate `ConcurrentDictionary`. But I also want to delete some values which are not present in data source anymore.

How to achieve this?

I know about constructing `ConcurrentDictionary` using `Dictionary` as a source. But this not applicable as I'm updating already existing `ConcurrentDictionary` and cannot periodically construct a new one.

** EDIT **

I can do this operation in two steps

1. Iterate thru source `Dictionary` and call `TryUpdate` on target `ConcurrentDictionary`.
2. Iterate thru target `ConcurrentDictionary` and delete every key that is not present in source `Dictionary`

But I'd like to have more elegant way if present

Comment: Do you want to add and delete safely (for lack of better words.. atomically)?

Comment: This is not about safety. This is about automatic deletion of absent keys. In ordinary cache entities which are not updated will expire and be deleted. In `Concurrentictionary` entities will stay forever. `TryUpdate` will only update entities which are exist in data source. But will not delete those which are has not been found

Comment: You wrote _...cannot periodically construct a new one…_. Why not?

Comment: Because I instantiate `ConcurrentDictionary` as singleton and use it as dependency in DI.
Project is based on NET Core 2.2 MVC `ConcurrentDictionary` updated in `HostedService`, and consumed in Values Controller

Comment: The `ConcurrentDictionary` is a low-level abstraction and making it exposed to DI I wouldn't consider a best practice. Instead I'd suggest to define a higher-level abstraction which would provide a cache functionality interface and encapsulate a dictionary or another data structure inside. As for the problem you're struggling with, it looks like you merely need a cache invalidation which definitely can be based on cache expiration in your case. I'd suggest to take a look at `System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache` which provides this out of box.

Comment: I don't use `System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache` because of  it has time based expiration. For some reasin `HostedService` may fail to do update (ex data source is unavailable) In such case cached data should stay for long time. And yes, I've created wrapper class for my `ConcurrentDictionary` and instantiate wrapper as singleton.

Comment: You're alluding to a relationship between your cache and a "data source" but it's not clear what you're describing. If `MemoryCache` is undesirable because it has a time based expiration then how do you determine when or why to update the values in the cache? It might help if you described the expected behavior in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Try having a background thread enumerating the ConcurrentDictionary and checking source.  If its not in source, remove it from the Dictionary.